# Understanding streams

Tags: javascript, web-development, programming-languages, node.js, stream-processing

I have started learning streaming APIs and I found one of the good documentations [here](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#introduction). There was a comparison given by author to demonstrate the effectiveness of the streams.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.txt', function (err, data) {
        res.end(data);
    });
});
server.listen(8000);
```

It is told that in the example above, for every request the whole file would be read and stored in memory which may create problems for large number of concurrent connections. Sounds good!

Now, for the solution in the second example:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.txt');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(8000);
```

it is told that since `res` is itself is a stream hence we can read the file via stream and pipe the result into res which would not create the memory issue.

**Question**

Will the browser would keep the connection open util the whole file is read since according to me the browser knows about `HTTP` only hence how would it handle the stream scenario. Also, wouldn't it take longer to stream the file vs sending whole file at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wouldn't it take longer to stream the file vs sending whole file at a time?

Welcome to the [time space tradeoff](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/space-time-tradeoff.html).  Reading a whole file into memory (say as an array or string) is called [slurping](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=402915).  It can be a good or bad idea depending on file size, available memory, and how many times you do it at the same time.

The alternative is [line by line processing](http://fastml.com/processing-large-files-line-by-line/) (or [chunk processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533570/in-powershell-how-do-i-split-a-large-binary-file) for binary files).  As smaller parts of the file come in they are acted on and then forgotten.  This keeps the memory footprint small but increases accessing overhead.  That's the tradeoff that you must balance.

Streams can do either.  When you offer access as a stream you're saying, "I don't know which you're about to do but here's where to get your data".  Once you have a stream you can dump it all in memory, act on smaller parts, or hand it to something else as a stream.

Comment: Ehm, I think only the Perl folks call it "slurping."

Comment: so, browser will keep its connection open until the whole file is read, right?

Comment: @CodeYogi - Yes.  And probably after that, too, because browsers tend to maintain open connections in case they're needed later.

Comment: @robertharvey if you'd care to suggest other names I'd be happy to add them.  I call it slurping regardless of whether the language has a library named slurp because the trade off issue is the same.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: Please don't tell people that "slurping" is a real term.  It's a word some Perl nut made up when they were trying to be cute. I've been in this industry a long time, and "slurping" has never been a thing, unless you're referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pod_slurping).  Nobody who wants to be taken seriously goes into a code review and declares "I wrote this code to slurp a file."

Comment: @robertharvey I've been in this industry since it was only 30 years old.  None of the terms are "real".  We beg, borrow, and steal terms from other industries let alone other programming languages. If you don't want a nomenclature debate then delete ALL your nomenclature debate comments.  If you insist on having one please make a better argument than name calling.

Comment: If you're actually one of those perl nuts, then I apologize for that.  Don't let it diminish my central point, though.  Young programmers have enough problems distinguishing terms from concepts without us throwing fictional ones at them.  Surely we have enough mental masturbation over SOLID and software patterns already.

Comment: @robertharvey You have a low threshold for "fictional terms". Since you insist on classifying me as some kind of nut before treating me with respect I'll admit to being a professional "nut" in the following categories: Perl, Python, Java, c#, c++, c, tasm, masm, php, JavaScript, Visual Basic (.net, and 6) and that's just what I've been paid to play with.  I see no problem using terms that originate from any these languages, or indeed stacks or ecosystems.  I asked if you had any other terms to use and you offered nothing new.  Please make your comments constructive.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: "Reading a whole file into memory" doesn't really need any special term, IMHO. It's already a short expression as it is. "Buffering a file in memory" would be another option, albeit a little more vague. -- That said I think your answer doesn't deserve the downvotes.

Comment: @stakx I appreciate the support.  It's true that it doesn't need any special term.  Just as, "in my humble opinion" doesn't need any special abbreviation.  Yet here we are.

Comment: @CandiedOrange this answer didn't get the attention it deserves at least no down votes, I respect your knowledge and hence would request if you feel to add more details then it would be great.

Comment: @CodeYogi yeah we got sidetracked. Can you give me a hint about what more you'd be interested in?